# How to maintain login state across AMP and non AMP Pages?

Tags: amp-html

Sample Use Case: How to maintain login state across AMP and non AMP Pages?

1. User goes to the canonical site ( say xyz.com), and logs in.
2. Some moments later, the same user goes to Google.com in mobile, and after searching for something, receives an AMP search result for a xyz AMP Page.
3. After clicking on the search result, the AMP Page is opened via AMP Viewer (that is it's served from the AMP Cache, not the site's origin)

Query 1: 
Based on the above use-case will the user be already logged-in the AMP experience (since the user logged-in through the canonical page first)?

Query 2: 
On which browsers the AMP-Cache to mobile site login is supported? (example, iOS might have problems with 3rd party cookies)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Based on the above use-case will the user be already logged-in the AMP experience (since the user logged-in through the canonical page first)?**

- In general, there would be no issue if the user visits the canonical
  page first and then the AMP via a viewer.
- Using a custom cookie for tracking between cached and publisher
  version is an option in this case.  Help Article Link which addresses
  a similar issue and has an example explained in detail:
  https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/poll/
- Additionally, this approach is also supported by amp-list, amp-state and amp-access.

**2. On which browsers the AMP-Cache to mSite login is supported (example, iOS might have problems with 3rd party cookies)?**

- In general, there would be no issue if the user visits the canonical
  page first and then the AMP via a viewer but the other way around
  wouldn't work because of iOS cookie policy.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Based on the above use-case will the user be already logged-in the AMP experience (since the user logged-in through the canonical page first)?**

Yes. The [amp-access](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-access/?format=websites) component allows you control what a user
    can see based on the their login state.

E.g.

```
<section>
  Welcome to the website! This section is visible to all.
</section>
<section amp-access="loggedIn">
  This section is only visible if you're logged in. Welcome back!
</section>
```

The component requires a couple of endpoints and URLs to make this possible:

```
<script id="amp-access" type="application/json">
  {
      "authorization": "/documentation/examples/api/amp-access/authorization?rid=READER_ID&url=CANONICAL_URL&ref=DOCUMENT_REFERRER&_=RANDOM",
      "pingback": "/documentation/examples/api/amp-access/pingback?rid=READER_ID&url=CANONICAL_URL&ref=DOCUMENT_REFERRER&_=RANDOM",
      "login": {
        "sign-in": "/documentation/examples/api/amp-access/login?rid=READER_ID&url=CANONICAL_URL",
        "sign-out": "/documentation/examples/api/amp-access/logout"
      },
      "authorizationFallbackResponse": {
          "error": true,
          "loggedIn": false,
          "powerUser": false
      }
  }
</script>
```

The amp-access component utilises the [AMP Reader ID](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-access/#amp-reader-id), which is an anonymous and unique identifier. The AMP Reader ID can be combined with authorisation cookies to track the login state of a user across AMP & non-AMP content.

**2. On which browsers the AMP-Cache to mSite login is supported (example, iOS might have problems with 3rd party cookies)?**

There will be some cases where Safari ITP may drop the AMP cookie within a very short time window. However, as the AMP reader ID is a stable identifier, you can associate the reader ID with the authorisation cookies and re-establish the cookie as needed.

As Safari uses machine learning to decide what to block and what not to, results can differ greatly from user to user and these issues are very hard to reproduce.

Some examples:

- If the user has blocked 3p cookies in general, they won't get cookies but you should still be able to get their Reader ID.
- If the user has blocked 3p cookies and Safari has decided google.com is a tracking domain, the Reader ID will not be available.